# How to keep magit from prompting me for my GitHub username

Tags: magit, github

I'd like to configure magit so that it does not prompt me for my GitHub username when it needs to interact with GitHub in some way (like, say, when doing a push).

My GitHub username is already in the `github.user` elisp variable and git variable, which should be enough according to the [ghub documentation](https://magit.vc/manual/ghub.html), but for some reason it keeps prompting me for my username every time I push.

magit gets my password from an external program which prompts me for my gpg key password which is used to decrypt my GitHub password in [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/), and that part works fine.

I also have [forge](https://magit.vc/manual/forge) set up to use [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/), and when using forge functions from magit I'm not prompted for my username, and only prompted for my gpg key password which decrypts my GitHub password in the same way it does for magit.  So if forge could be set up not to prompt for my username, I'd expect there should be some way to configure magit act the same.

Here is my setup:

In my emacs config:

```cl
(require 'auth-source-pass)
(setq auth-sources '(password-store))
(add-hook 'magit-process-find-password-functions
          'magit-process-password-auth-source))
(setq github.user "myusername")
```

From a shell, I typed:

```
git config --global github.user myusername
```

So now my `~/.gitconfig` contains:

```
[github]
    user = myusername
```

My `~/.password-store` directory tree looks like this:

```
.
├── api.github.com
│   └── myusername^forge.gpg
└── github.com
    └── myusername.gpg
```

I also tried sticking `^magit` after `myusername` and putting both of these variations under `api.github.com`, like the forge entry was, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

I use `pass` and the `password` package in Emacs but for GitHub/GitLab interaction I use [SSH keys](https://blog.g3rt.nl/upgrade-your-ssh-keys.html).  Upload your public key to your account and use something like [keychain](https://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) to store your keys on initial login.

Ocassionally I find Emacs doesn't find the Keychain agent so I've the following key-binding to reload..

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c k") 'keychain-refresh-environment)
```

Comment: The keychain-refresh-environment command is part of a separate emacs packet keychain-environment. See
https://github.com/tarsius/keychain-environment